# Undefined control sequence.\BState ->\State \algbackskip \BState

Tags: algorithmicx

I got the error while creating a pseudocode for my report. The following is my code in LaTeX. This gives out an stating "undefined control sequence `\BState` ->`\State \algbackskip \BState`". Kindly help me out with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \BState \emph{\textbf{Key(s)}}:
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that is causing this problem is an underfined `\@algbackskip` (which forms part of `\BState`).

The main [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) code - [`algorithmicx.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty) - contains a definitions for `\@algbackskip`, but it's been commented out:

```
%\def\algbackskip{\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
```

My assumption is that this might be a mistake and should be corrected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
% Reinsert missing \algbackskip
\def\algbackskip{\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State something
  \If{this}
    \State do this
    \BState do that
  \EndIf
  \BState now this
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, `\BState` is not even mentioned in the manual for `algorithmicx`.