# How to add input and output before algorithm procedure

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I am using ACM format for writing a paper. I use the following algorithm sample that is taken from this form. I want to add **input** and **output** before MyProcedure. I tried many ways but all fails. Can someone guide me? Thank you

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     % Input:
     % Output: 
    \Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
    \State $\textit{stringlen} \gets \text{length of }\textit{string}$
    \State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
    \BState \emph{top}:
    \If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
    \EndIf
    \State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
    \BState \emph{loop}:
    \If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
    \State $j \gets j-1$.
    \State $i \gets i-1$.
    \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
    \State \textbf{close};
    \EndIf
    \State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
    \State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
    \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Input x,y with:`\Procedure{Algo name}{$x,y$}`. Or `\Comment{Input: }` and `\Comment{Output:}`

Comment: Here is an example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215651/124842

Comment: @Bobyandbob Would you like to write up an answer, or is that question a duplicate? (I didn't look at it.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No the link is an alternativ with `algorithm`, but Steven do not respond to comments. Nevertheless i added some ideas.

Comment: Does the answer fits your question?

Answer (score 24):

***Answer:***

To add input and output before MyProcedure a possibility is to add the text before `\begin{algorithmic}` with starred hspace `\hspace*{}`([see 6.3.3 Horizontal Space](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)) and the indentation `\algorithmicindent` ([see 4.1 Blocks and loops](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx?lang=de)). LaTeX normally removes horizontal space at the beginning of a line, to preserve this space, use the starred version.

```
 ...
 \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Input} \\
 \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Output} 
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 ...
```

[image]

***Complete full MWE:***
A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

To complete the MWE and to avoid the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \BState ->\State \algbackskip l.24
>   \BState

You have to use the following definition (the solution is from @Werner see: [Undefined control sequence.\BState ->\State \algbackskip \BState](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292289/124842)):

```
\makeatletter
% Reinsert missing \algbackskip
\def\algbackskip{\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
% Reinsert missing \algbackskip
\def\algbackskip{\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Input} \\
    \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Output} 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
%    \Procedure{MyProcedure}{$x,y$}
%     % Input:
%     \Comment{Input: x}
%     % Output:
%     \Comment{Output:y}
    \State $\textit{stringlen} \gets \textit{length of } \textit{string}$
    \State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
    \BState \emph{top}:
    \If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
    \EndIf
    \State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
    \BState \emph{loop}:
    \If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
    \State $j \gets j-1$.
    \State $i \gets i-1$.
    \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
    \State \textbf{close};
    \EndIf
    \State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
    \State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
    \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Alternative**: You can add the input and output after `MyProcedure` with `\Procedure{MyProcedure}{$x,y$}` ...

[image]

or `\Comment{Input: x}`/`\Comment{Output: y}`.

[image]

Comment: How could I add comments in your code, I have tried `\tcp*{comment}` which did not work

Comment: With `\Comment{Your comment}` for example. See MWE.

Comment: What does `MWE` stand for?

Comment: A minimal working example (MWE), shown in the answer. You just have to remove %. Does it help?(\Comment{Your comment})

Comment: yes sir thank you

Answer (score 10):

If one is using the `algorithmic` environment, one can make `\REQUIRE` and `\ENSURE` to print `Input` and `Output` by [adding](http://tipstrickshowtos.blogspot.com/2010/11/replace-require-and-ensure-with-input.html) in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
```

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to keep `\REQUIRE` and `\ENSURE` as it are, and define custom commands for `\INPUT` and `\OUTPUT`?

Comment: I agree with the author since this is the exact same thing recommended in the section [3.14.3 Customization] in the documentation for the library: https://texdoc.org/pkg/algorithms