# hspace* does vertical space instead of horizontal space in algorithm block

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithmicx

I tried to use the algorithmic package to write down a pseudo code.

```
\begin{algorithm}
   \caption{caption}
   \Require $n\in \N$, fixed time $T>0$
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State T        
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Then I get the following output:[image]

So I tried adding the indent at Require so that it starts on a line with the rest and therefore I used the solution of this post ([How to add input and output before algorithm procedure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355937/how-to-add-input-and-output-before-algorithm-procedure)) and added \hspace*{\algorithmicindent}, i.e.

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{caption}
    \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \Require $n\in \N$, fixed time $T>0$
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State T
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

But instead of horizontal indent i get vertical indent: [image]

Since I don't get any error message either, I'm a bit lost as to why it misinterprets the command like that. Does anyone know what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `Require` is starting a new paragraph so your `\hspace*` is not making vertical space it is making a single line paragraph with just a horizontal space

You would see the same if you used `\hspace*` before `\section` or `\begin{quote}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense. Do you know a workaround?